# Multi threading in Tkinter GUI, threads in different classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm currently learning the Tkinter GUI programming. And I'm stuck in somewhere in multi threading concept. Even though this topic is discussed several times here, I couldn't catch the concept and apply it to my small sample program.

Below is my code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style
from Tkinter import *
import time


class Widgets(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI(parent)

    def initUI(self, parent):
        self.parent.title("Count Numbers")

        for r in range(10):
            self.parent.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)    
        for c in range(10):
            self.parent.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)        

        self.button1 = Button(parent, text = "count")
        self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )
        self.button1["command"] = self.countNum

        self.button2 = Button(parent, text = "say Hello")
        self.button2.grid(row = 1, column = 7, rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S) 
        self.button2["command"] = PrintHello(self).helloPrint

    def countNum(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print i
            time.sleep(2)   

class PrintHello(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()
        self.parent = parent

    def helloPrint(self):
        print "Hello"

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    app = Widgets(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

The output is a GUI with 2 buttons- first one prints the numbers and second prints "Hello". But on clicking the first button, the GUI gets **frozen** while the numbers are getting printed. And while searching for a solution, I found that 'multi threading' may help. But after several attempts, I couldn't apply multi-threading to my sample program given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need threading for something this simple.

The GUI is freezing because you're putting a `time.sleep` inside the function which is blocking the main thread until it's finished.

Simply use Tk's built in `after` method. Change your function to.

```
def countNum(self, num=0):
    if num < 10:
        print num
        root.after(2000, lambda: self.countNum(num + 1))
    else:
        print "Stopping after call"
```

The `after` method takes the following arguments:

```
after(delay_ms, callback, arguments)
```

The time is in milliseconds, and 1000 ms = 1 second. So, we pass 2,000 ms for a 2 second delay.

Answer (score 7):

Pythonista's answer is excellent. But I'd like to touch upon some additional points.

- GUI's are *event-driven*. They run in a loop processing events, calling pieces of your code (called callbacks) every now and then. So your code is more or less a guest in the event-loop. As you have noticed, your pieces of code should finish quickly otherwise they stall event processing making the GUI unresponsive. This is a completely different programming model from the linear programs that is often seen in tutorials. To perform longer-running calculations or tasks you can split them up in small pieces and use `after`. Or you could to them in another process with `multiprocessing`. But then you'd still need to check periodically (with `after` again) if they have finished.

The following points stem from the fact that doing multithreading right is *hard*.

- CPython (the most used Python implementation) has what is called a Global Interpreter Lock. This ensures that only *one thread at a time* can be executing Python bytecode. When other threads are busy executing Python bytecode, the thread running the GUI is doing nothing.
  So multithreading is not a certain solution to the problem of an unresponsive GUI.
- <strike>a lot of GUI toolkits are not thread-safe, and tkinter is not an exception. This means that you should *only* make tkinter calls from the thread that's running the `mainloop`.</strike> (In Python 3.x, `tkinter` has been made thread safe.)