# "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Treasure Island type game using tkinter and trying to increase the font size while having a sort of typerwriter effect that prints out the letters one by one. I've gottten them to work by themselves but when I put them both together I get the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" in line 39.

code:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Treasure Island")
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

logo = tkinter.Label(window, text='''
          |                   |                  |                     |
 _________|________________.=""_;=.______________|_____________________|_______
|                   |  ,-"_,=""     `"=.|                  |
|___________________|__"=._o`"-._        `"=.______________|___________________
          |                `"=._o`"=._      _`"=._                     |
 _________|_____________________:=._o "=._."_.-="'"=.__________________|_______
|                   |    __.--" , ; `"=._o." ,-"""-._ ".   |
|___________________|_._"  ,. .` ` `` ,  `"-._"-._   ". '__|___________________
          |           |o`"=._` , "` `; .". ,  "-._"-._; ;              |
 _________|___________| ;`-.o`"=._; ." ` '`."\` . "-._ /_______________|_______
|                   | |o;    `"-.o`"=._``  '` " ,__.--o;   |
|___________________|_| ;     (#) `-.o `"=.`_.--"_o.-; ;___|___________________
____/______/______/___|o;._    "      `".o|o_.--"    ;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/_"=._o--._        ; | ;        ; ;/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/__"=._o--._   ;o|o;     _._;o;____/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/____"=._o._; | ;_.--"o.--"_/______/______/______/_
____/______/______/______/______/_____"=.o|o_.--""___/______/______/______/____
/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/______/_____ /
''')

logo.pack()
logo.config(font=('length', 15))

line1 = tkinter.Label(window, text="Welcome to Treasure Island,\n"
                                   "Your goal is to find the buried Treasure!")

line1.config(font=('length', 15))
label1 = tkinter.StringVar()

a = tkinter.Label(textvariable=label1)

a.pack()
for i in line1:
      a=label1.get()
      label1.set(a+i)
      window.after(50)
      window.update()

space = tkinter.Label(window, text=" \n \n ")

space.pack()
```

Comment: What confuses you about the error message? `a` is a string and `i` is an integer. `+` doesn't make sense for those two types. That's what the error message tells you

Comment: How do ii fix the problem though?

Comment: You need both arguments to be of the same type. If you want to add them like numbers (assuming `a` contains something that looks like a number), then do `int(a) + i`. If you intended to concatenate them so that the two values appear one after the other in the resulting string, you want `a + str(i)`

Comment: when I do either of the solutions if still gives me the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Comment: You said line 39, but line 39 in your code is the blank line before `a.pack()`. I was giving advice for line 43, assuming you were off by a few. Can you confirm which line the error is coming from in your code snippet?

Comment: The error is on the line `for i in line1:`.  What do you want to do actually?

Comment: The exact error is Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 41, in <module>
    for i in line1:
, line 1681, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: acw1668 I want it to print out the letters in the text 1 by 1 sort of like a typewriter heres the post i got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059668/typewriter-effect-in-tkinter

Comment: which i got it to do but I'm trying to find a way of making the text bigger while doing the "typewriter effect"

Comment: I think you need to change `line1` from a widget to simply a string containing the text only.

Comment: acw1668 I've tried that before but if I try to use the increase size part on line 35 it gives me the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: If you change it to a string, you should not call `.config()` on it because it is not a label anymore.

Comment: What can I call then to change the font size?

Comment: What do you mean by *"change the font size"*? Do you mean that you will change the font size during the *typewriter* animation? Actually you can set the font size when creating label `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text in your `line1` label character by character and show it in sequence, maybe this is what you need

```
for i in line1.cget("text"):
    a=label1.get()
    label1.set(a+i)
    window.after(50)
    window.update()
```

Comment: This works but even with "line1.config(font=('length', 15))" It doesn't increase the font size do you have any idea why?

Comment: Because you copy characters from `line1` to `label1` string so you set config for `line1` does not work for `label1` string. Otherwise `label1` string belongs to `a` label. So you need to config `a` label to `a = tkinter.Label(textvariable=label1, font=("Arial", 25))` will work