# Executing multiple Python commands at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I was wondering what the easiest way to execute two or more commands at the same time in python. For example:

```
from turtle import *

turtle_one=Turtle()
turtle_two=Turtle()
turtle_two.left(180)
#The lines to be executed at the same time are below.
turtle_one.forward(100)
turtle_two.forward(100)
```

Comment: I ma writing this comment just to note that this has less to do with executing things in parallel in Python (to which there are several solutions) and more to do with executing animations in parallel using Python's Turtle module - which will both restrict one's options, and likely force an specific solution in a separate layer of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can effectively do this using the timer event that comes with the turtle module:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle_one = Turtle(shape="turtle")
turtle_one.setheading(30)
turtle_two = Turtle(shape="turtle")
turtle_two.setheading(210)

# The lines to be executed at the same time are below.
def move1():
    turtle_one.forward(5)

    if turtle_one.xcor() < 100:
        screen.ontimer(move1, 50)

def move2():
    turtle_two.forward(10)

    if turtle_two.xcor() > -100:
        screen.ontimer(move2, 100)

screen = Screen()

move1()
move2()

screen.exitonclick()
```

With respect to threads, as suggested by others, read up on the issues discussed in posts like [Multi threading in Tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969724/multi-threading-in-tkinter-gui-threads-in-different-classes) as Python's turtle module is built on Tkinter and that recent post notes:

> a lot of GUI toolkits are not thread-safe, and tkinter is not an
>   exception

Comment: Thanks, this works really well! The only problem is that it does not actually do both at once, it just repeats them in rapid succession.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the threading module.

```
from turtle import *
from threading import Thread

turtle_one=Turtle()
turtle_two=Turtle()
turtle_two.left(180)

Thread(target=turtle_one.forward, args=[100]).start()
Thread(target=turtle_two.forward, args=[100]).start()
```

This starts the `turtle_one/two.forward` function in the background, with 100 as an argument.

To make it easier, make a `run_in_background` function...

```
def run_in_background(func, *args):
    Thread(target=func, args=args).start()

run_in_background(turtle_one.forward, 100)
run_in_background(turtle_two.forward, 100)
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for turtle graphics, however it works very nicely for other things such as printing, waiting, and printing again. Thank you.

Comment: @coDE_RP what versions of Python and Turtle are you using? It worked for me.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2, and Turtle 1.1b

Comment: Ah ok. I'm on Python 2.7, so that would probably make the difference.