# Tkinter isn't respoding while loop is running! PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was just programming basic spam program that I could come up with in python.
However when I press "Spam" button in the Tkinter window,It wont respond until function is ended :(! 
Here is the code :

```
import pyautogui
import time
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x250")

def retrive_input():
  inputValue = textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
  spams(inputValue)
  print(inputValue)


textBox = Text(root,height=5,width=30)
textBox.grid(row=1)
buttonCommit = Button(root,height=1,width=10,text="Spam 
Word!",command=lambda:retrive_input())
buttonCommit.grid(row=2)


def spams(wordtospam):
  x_cor = 962
  y_cor=541
  pyautogui.click(962,541)
  for i in range(9999):
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.typewrite(wordtospam)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.typewrite('random stuff')
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(8)


upali = True



#spams('')

root.mainloop()
```

I also want to add a keydown checker, so if I press (for example) f5, program will stop working until I press f4.
Thanks ahead!
(This is in game program that will spam me something :), so to type in game u press enter, typewrite, enter and it sends )

Comment: this is because of `sleep()`. In tkinter you don't want to use `sleep()` but `after()` instead.

Comment: This is a fairly common issue, this answer should help you out :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/36969786/8506575

Comment: if you are running code then tkinter wont be able to update the screen

Comment: I have another problem "name 'after' is not defined" and "TypeError: spams() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xywords'"